# My email was used as the From: address on a spam and now I'm getting hundreds of auto-replies

Tags: email, spam-prevention, auto-reply

I have a vanity domain with email hosted by GMail and forwarded to my regular Gmail account.  It appears that the **From:** line of the primary address I use has been spoofed on multiple Spam messages, and lately I have been receiving a ton of auto-replies from random addresses (i.e. not ones in my addressbook).

While most of the bounces (e.g. from Postmaster, MAILER-DAEMON, Mail Delivery System, etc.) are caught by the first gmail account and not forwarded on, a small number of them are still getting through to my regular account.  Is there anything I can do at this point to stop this or prevent the emails from being created in the first place?

I've got two-factor authentication set up in both places, strong passwords, and there's nothing in the Sent Mail outboxes of either of the accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual. However, usually this is a one time spam and the spammer moves on. It should stop soon. There is no way to stop a spammer form pretending to come from your address.

Comment: I just added an SPF record to my DNS.  Will that help?  Would a DKIM be possible?  I don't normally actually login to my domain account, but use Gmail's "Send Mail As" feature to spoof my vanity domain address.

Comment: I just added DKIM to my DNS entries as well, and at least I can send/receive messages on there to/from my work accounts.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the spam problem?

Comment: My understanding is that having SPF and DKIM in your DNS should help as both purport to be technologies that help confirm that an email is legitimately sent and not a spoofed message. 

While I also understand that a receiving server might just ignore them, if mail servers silently discarded the spams rather than replying with postmaster or unknown account emails, that would help.  I simply don't know if spam filters/mail servers silently discard SPF or non-DKIM validated messages or if they still respond with bounces